# R - tidyverse approach to split a dataframe by columns and keep a set of common columns

Tags: r

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708011/split-dataframe-by-column-and-keep-a-set-of-common-columns-in-each-subset), but I would prefer to have a tidyverse approach.

I have a dataset with several columns and I want to split it columnwise (***not rowwise***!), but keep a list of common columns in every dataset. To illustrate this, I will use the `iris` dataset, and let's say that `Species` is the common column that I want to keep.

It would be really easy to do it using just these simple operations:

```
iris1 <- iris[,c("Species", "Sepal.Width")]
iris2 <- iris[,c("Species", "Sepal.Length")]
iris3 <- iris[,c("Species", "Petal.Width")]
iris4 <- iris[,c("Species", "Petal.Length")]
```

So I want to achieve the same output as that, but in a tidyverse style and usable in a pipeline without breaking it.

Comment: Often a "tidyverse style" might encourage using nested dataframes.  The nested column is in fact a list of dataframes, but the whole thing is packaged in a way that can also hold the output of whatever you do next.  Just a consideration

Comment: This feels like it might be an XY problem. What is the larger thing you are trying to do that is making it seem necessary to do this step? There might be a simpler approach that makes this unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to make a function that extracts from iris the Species and the column (number or name) of your choice, then map those column numbers into your function.

```
library(dplyr)
make_df <- function(col) { iris %>% select(Species, {{ col }} )}
c(2,1,4,3) %>% purrr::map(make_df)
```

or as one line:

```
c(2,1,4,3) %>% map(~iris %>% select(Species, {{ .x }}))
```

This will output a list with four elements, each of which is a data frame like you describe. For many workflows that will be safer and more convenient than creating four free-floating data frames in the global environment.

```
c(2,1,4,3) %>% map(make_df) %>% map(head)

[[1]]
  Species Sepal.Width
1  setosa         3.5
2  setosa         3.0
3  setosa         3.2
4  setosa         3.1
5  setosa         3.6
6  setosa         3.9

[[2]]
  Species Sepal.Length
1  setosa          5.1
2  setosa          4.9
3  setosa          4.7
4  setosa          4.6
5  setosa          5.0
6  setosa          5.4

[[3]]
  Species Petal.Width
1  setosa         0.2
2  setosa         0.2
3  setosa         0.2
4  setosa         0.2
5  setosa         0.2
6  setosa         0.4

[[4]]
  Species Petal.Length
1  setosa          1.4
2  setosa          1.4
3  setosa          1.3
4  setosa          1.5
5  setosa          1.4
6  setosa          1.7
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you maybe write how the code would look like if it started with `iris %>%` ? I tried `iris %>% 
map(~. %>% select(Species, {{ c(2,1,4,3) }}))`, but that doesn't work.