# splitting a list of data frames per variable

Tags: r, split

I have a list of 13 data frames. I need to split each data frame into several ones. The id columns (multiple per data frame) should remain in all of the resulting data frames. Apart from the id columns I need only one variable per resulting data frame. For instance if df1 has 3 id columns and 6 other variables, I will have six data frames each including 4 columns: 3 id columns and one variable. I should do this for all data frames in my list.
Here is a dummy sample:

```
obj1 <- list(bodyPart = c("leg", "arm", "knee"),side = c("LEFT", "RIGHT", "LEFT"), device = c("LLI", "LSM", "GHT"), length = c(12, 476, 7), id = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), mwID = c("a12", "k87", "j98")) %>%  as.data.frame()
obj2 <- list(bodyPart = c("ankel", "ear", "knee"), side = c("LEFT", "LEFT", "LEFT"), device = c("GOM", "LSM", "YYY"), id = c("ZZ", "DD", "FF"), tqID = c("kj8", "ll23", "sc26")) %>%  as.data.frame()

x <- list(foo = obj1, bar = obj2)
```

Desired output would look like this:

```
obj1_1 <- list(id = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), mwID = c("a12", "k87", "j98"), bodyPart = c("leg", "arm", "knee")) %>%  as.data.frame()
obj1_2 <- list( id = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), mwID = c("a12", "k87", "j98"), length = c(12.43, 476, 7.14)) %>%  as.data.frame()
obj1_3 <- list(side = c("LEFT", "RIGHT", "LEFT"), id = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), mwID = c("a12", "k87", "j98")) %>%  as.data.frame()
.
.
.
obj2_1 <- list(id = c("ZZ", "DD", "FF"), tqID = c("kj8", "ll23", "sc26"), bodyPart = c("ankel", "ear", "knee")) %>%  as.data.frame()
.
.
.
```

After this, I need to save each dataframe as a csv file excluding all NA rows.
I have already tried to apply the solution I found in another post but get stuck in the middle of it ([Split dataframe by column and keep a set of common columns in each subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708011/split-dataframe-by-column-and-keep-a-set-of-common-columns-in-each-subset)). I would really appreciate your help on this.
Based on the solution offered in the post mentioned earlier, I should first take the id columns out of each data frame and then specify the number of parts each data frame is going to split into. The first thing I get stuck in is how to reach the desired level to show the number of variables per data frame because the number of splits is the number of variables. I wrote a for loop but I am not sure where the problem lies.

```
id_cols <- c("id", "mwID", "tqID")
var_cols <- list()
df_parts <- list()
for (table_name in names(x)) {
  var_cols[[table_name]] <- x[[table_name]] %>% 
    select(-c(id, ends_with('ID')))
  for (var_name in names(var_cols)) {
    print(var_name)
    n_parts[[table_name]] <- length(var_cols[[table_name]])
    df_parts <- split(
      var_cols, 
      cut(
        seq_along(var_cols), 
        n_parts[[table_name]], 
        labels = FALSE
      )
    ) |>
    lapply(\(v) x[, c(id_cols, v)])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cbind` the id-columns to the `asplit`ted non-id columns. To separate them, use  `setdiff` and `intersect`.

```
res <- lapply(lst, \(x, y) {
  as <- asplit(x[setdiff(names(x), y)], 2)
  lapply(names(as) |> setNames(names(as)), \(z) cbind(x[intersect(names(x), y)], as[z]))
}, id_cols) |> unlist(recursive=FALSE)
```

To `write.csv`, `lapply` over the `names`.

```
lapply(names(res), \(x) write.csv(res[[x]], sprintf('%s.csv', x), row.names=FALSE))
```

---

*Data:*

```
lst <- list(foo = structure(list(bodyPart = c("leg", "arm", "knee"), 
    side = c("LEFT", "RIGHT", "LEFT"), device = c("LLI", "LSM", 
    "GHT"), length = c(12, 476, 7), id = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), 
    mwID = c("a12", "k87", "j98")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), bar = structure(list(bodyPart = c("ankel", "ear", "knee"
), side = c("LEFT", "LEFT", "LEFT"), device = c("GOM", "LSM", 
"YYY"), id = c("ZZ", "DD", "FF"), tqID = c("kj8", "ll23", "sc26"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))

id_cols <- c("id", "mwID", "tqID")
```

Comment: Thanks! I should add that the number of id columns per data frame varies. How can I take that into account?

Comment: @Rara As long as you provide names of all ID columns in `id_cols`, this should work automatically because they are passed by the `y` argument into `intersect(names(lst$foo), id_cols)`. Try the code within `{}` using `x <- lst$foo; y <- id_cols` and you will understand.

Comment: Hi! I am still struggling to understand your magic code. I would really appreciate your help. I understand that `\(x, y)` is a function with two variables. But could you please explain what x and y refer to in my data in this code?

Comment: I also don't understand where `id_cols` is used. Does it refer to `y`?

Comment: @Rara Appreciate your eagerness to understand the code. `lapply` can process more than just one argument; additional arguments are stated after the `FUN`ction. (In contrast to `Map`, which processes each element of the additional arguments one after the other, `lapply` processes all elements of the additional arguments at once.)  Actually it's easy if you look at this small example `lapply(1:3, \(x, y) x + y, 10)`; the `10` gets passed as `y`. Here also a quick `Map` example: `Map(\(x, y) x + y, 1:3, c(10, 20, 30))`. Cheers!

Comment: Many thanks for your clear explanations. Made my life much easier!

Comment: Pleasure, @Rara

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that takes as input a list of data.frames, and applies, for each data.frame in the list, a selecting function `[`:

```r
split_list <- 
  function(l, n = 2){
  
  # For each data.frame, 
  lapply(l, \(data){

    #Count the number of columns, assuming the number of columns to keep is `n` (2 by default), 
    #and they are located at the end of the data.frame
    nc = ncol(data)
    lsel <- lapply(1:(nc-n), \(x) c(x, (nc-n+1):nc))

    #Apply the `[` function on the set of selecting indices defined above
    lapply(lsel, \(col) data[col])
  })
}
```

```r
split_list(x)

# $foo
# $foo[[1]]
#   bodyPart id mwID
# 1      leg AA  a12
# 2      arm BB  k87
# 3     knee CC  j98
# 
# $foo[[2]]
#    side id mwID
# 1  LEFT AA  a12
# 2 RIGHT BB  k87
# 3  LEFT CC  j98
# 
# $foo[[3]]
#   device id mwID
# 1    LLI AA  a12
# 2    LSM BB  k87
# 3    GHT CC  j98
# 
# $foo[[4]]
#   length id mwID
# 1     12 AA  a12
# 2    476 BB  k87
# 3      7 CC  j98
# 
# 
# $bar
# $bar[[1]]
#   bodyPart id tqID
# 1    ankel ZZ  kj8
# 2      ear DD ll23
# 3     knee FF sc26
# 
# $bar[[2]]
#   side id tqID
# 1 LEFT ZZ  kj8
# 2 LEFT DD ll23
# 3 LEFT FF sc26
# 
# $bar[[3]]
#   device id tqID
# 1    GOM ZZ  kj8
# 2    LSM DD ll23
# 3    YYY FF sc26
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you kindly explain this part a bit? `lapply(1:(nc-n), \(x) c(x, (nc-n+1):nc))`

Comment: Yes: it creates the list of column indices you want for the subsets. `nc` is the number of column of the data.frame, and `n` is the number of `id` columns (in your case, 2). If nc = 5 and n = 2, you'll get `1 4 5`, `2 4 5`, and `3 4 5`.

Comment: Thanks! I am now stuck with the different id columns per data frame. The number of id columns vary per data frame.  They also appear as the first columns. Could you please help with that too?

Comment: My function cannot accomodate for it, but I believe jay.sf's can. try it out!